# Data Backup into Google Servers using Android Backup Service in Android

Tags: android, android-backup-service

Im trying to do the backing up of my application's data into the Google Servers..

For doing this I've implemented a `BackupAgent` in my code and I included this in the Android  Manifest file and "Meta-data" ( Got after registered my Application's package with the [Android Backup Service](https://developers.google.com/android/backup/))

When I run the application to do the backup this is not performing the backup.. Im using Nexus one device (connected to WIFI also) .

Could any one please let me know why it is not calling my BackupAgent's `onBackup()` method?

Am I missing some thing, to include in the Android manifest file or some where in the program?

---

The below is my manifest file..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.simpledatabackup"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent"
                 android:debuggable="true">


        <activity android:name=".SimpleDatabackup"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
                   android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAIZn2ysSLR5wNbcq1uaoWQO0HuipMetQENVTsilw" />

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

and the source file is

```
public class SimpleDatabackup extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences myPrefs ;         // Shared Preferences

    BackupManager mBackupManager;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = myPrefs.edit();
        edit.putString("firstname", "uday") ;
        edit.putString("lastname", "kiran") ;
        edit.commit() ;

        mBackupManager.dataChanged();   



    }
}
```

My Backup Agent is some thing like this: I have not implemented the functionality inside is onBackup() and onRestore(). Once if it is called i will implement what ever i want..

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgent {

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    System.out.println("In MyBackuAgent's onCreate() method");

}

@Override
public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor arg0, BackupDataOutput arg1,
        ParcelFileDescriptor arg2) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("In MyBackuAgent's onBackup()");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
        ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {

}

}
```

Comment: Could you show snippets of your backupAgent and what you added to your manifest?  How have you determined that onBackup isn't being called?

Answer (score 4):

In the application tag in the manifest include

```
android:allowBackup="true" 
android:restoreAnyVersion="true" 
android:backupAgent="<package>.MyBackupAgent"
```

Please follow the ["Testing your BackupAgent"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) section to invoke the backup instantly for testing.

BackupManagerService schedules the backup regularly in hour interval after the datachanged call to backupmanager. [[grepcode]](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/com/android/server/BackupManagerService.java)

Comment: +1 for fishing out the source code and noticing the one-hour delay